# Solr field is string while Sitecore search is passing text field type

Tags: solr, indexing

We have upgraded from Sitecore 8 to Sitecore 10.1 and also updated Solr 6.6.2 to Solr 8.4

Some of the search from Solr was returning null. Upon investigation, I found out that the field type in Solr is `string (_s)`. While in the Search log, the type passed in a query is `text (_t)`.

As an example, the field in Solr is `sustainabilitycasestudytag_s` while in the search log, the query is `sustainabilitycasestudytag_t_en:("Climate Change")`.

I had to fix this by adding the field in Solr

```
<field fieldName="sustainabilitycasestudytag" returnType="stringCollection" />
```

After index rebuilding, the results from Solr are coming correctly.

I have found this issue with 3 or more fields and in order to fix this, I have added the `returnType="stringCollection"` in the config.

There may be other pages with the similar issue, is there any permanent way to fix this?. The fields in Solr are `string(_s)` while in the Search log, it is passed as `text (_t)`

Here is the code

```
[IndexField("sustainabilitycasestudytag")]
public virtual string Tag { get; set; }

private Expression<Func<SustainabilityCaseStudySearchItem, bool>> ApplySustainabilityCaseStudyTagFilter(Expression<Func<SustainabilityCaseStudySearchItem, bool>> filterPredicate)
        {
            var tagFilter = "Climate Change";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagFilter))
            {
                return filterPredicate.And(x => x.Tag.Equals(tagFilter));
            }

            return filterPredicate;
        }
```

Comment: What field type is `sustainabilitycasestudytag` in Sitecore?  Is it a computed field?  How are you querying this field in the Content Search API?  Can you share the code?

Comment: its not a computed field. I have updated the question with the code @ChetCheeto

Comment: And also use string instead stringCollection if the field holds one string value. I also faced this issue and ended up adding the field in config like you did.

Comment: And what type of field is `sustainabilitycasestudytag`?  Sitecore will generally treat a RichText field as Text datatype in Solr, but a Single-line text field is treated as a string datatype.

Comment: @ChetCheeto its a dropdownlist field